# remove first few contents from view list drupal7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a content type "Example".
I have 15 contents for that content type.I need to create 2 different views.

1st view.) which will be having the recently added/updated contents(Which I got.)

2nd view.) which needs to be with the rest of 10 contents from the 1st view(In simple words the last updated 10 contents from the content type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jsheffers's answer is good if your contents are fixed in number.

In case your total varies it couldn't be used. Also it would make old content show up on top which in many case is not the desired one.

so here is my solution.

1. Create a view to display five items.
2. Clone the page/block and enable pager or display all items. Now click to open the extra settings of pager or display all items. Here you would get a field where you could input **Offset**. You can now give an offset of '5' in here and save.

   Pasting below the description of Offset as it appear in admin interface.

> The number of items to skip. For example, if this field is 3, the
> first 3 items will be skipped and not displayed.

Also attaching a screenshot to make it more clearer.
[image]

Comment: Yes..Exactly what I did for this and got the result. This is what the view concept goes for such requirement.
Great Help...D34dman

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Create a view that lists out the 5 most recently updated pieces of content.

**Step 2**

Create another view that lists out the 10 mosts recently updated pieces of content, and then switch the sort to desc.

The five most recently updated will show in view one and the other 10 will show in the second view.  If you want both views to be on the same page, you could add one of the views to the header of the view you would like to be the main page.

Comment: This can be useful only for 15 contents.right?If there are more than that then it wont show me few more contents.
Sorry, 15 was given in question just for an example.

Comment: @jsheffers is not wrong, most of the time you get answers for what have been asked for. Not what you "want" exactly. So next time when you form a question be more close to "what" you want, you are more likely to get a correct answer :).(my reply to Aniruddhsinh's comment ).